# Presto could not read avro table on hive

Tags: avro, amazon-emr, presto

I am using Presto 0.238.3, it is preinstalled on EMR 6.2 . I have some avro tables, on Hive I can query this tables, but presto cannot query them. I got following exceptions

**error initializing deserializer: com.facebook.presto.hive.avro.PrestoAvroSerDe**

What and at which place should I update, all the guidance are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding following configuration, it works.

```
{
        "classification": "core-site",
        "properties": {
            "metastore.storage.schema.reader.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.SerDeStorageSchemaReader"
}
```